# unwanted (text) after using include

Tags: php, css, include

I have a index.php and a header.php which will be included in index.php
after using

```
include('header.php')
```

an unwanted "" will apear in html source.
header.php containes pure html but has .php extension.
It will put an unwanted 20px in height free space above the header.
please help me remove that.

this is source:
[image]

this is style:
[image]

and finally this is header.php:

```
<div id="logo"></div>
<div id="header_top">
    <div id="search">
        <a href="main.html">main</a><span class="verbarheader_padding">|</span>
        <a href="history.html">history</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Inspect element, find out what element the "" is inside. We can't fix it without knowing that

Comment: We need more details... seriously.

Comment: remove leading and trailing spaces in header.php e.g. here<?php and ?>here  Other than that try output buffering

Comment: Hi, you have to show us the code so that we could point out the mistake. It would most probably be an extra space in your html. :)

Comment: @Andy edited the post so you may have a look at my code. thanks!

Comment: @Waygood there is no extra space there to remove!

Comment: I will have to ask the same question that I deleted just few minutes ago. Is that unwanted spaces (blanks) or unwanted quotation marks that appear in the code?

Comment: @GermannArlington unwanted quotation marks. there is no space

Comment: Then you should look for undefined or empty strings variables in your header.php

Comment: @bijibuji Include your html code please, that is where the "" are coming from

Comment: @GermannArlington as I mentioned earlier , header.php has pure html ansd just has php extension! there is no such string variable to remove or so

Comment: @bijibuji Sorry I should have been clearer, can you give us the .php code, not the html output

Comment: If that IS the case then RENAME your header.php to header.html and check if the result changes. If you force PHP to parse pure HTML don't be too surprised if it (PHP) finds something to process.

Comment: @Andy there is no php in header.php. it is pure html.

Comment: @GermannArlington then how can I include it in my index.php? is php able to include html extension in some other php code?

Comment: Yes, it can - you can include ANY file

Comment: @GermannArlington after using html extension the problem already exists and nothing changed! :(

Comment: looks like its occurring BEFORE header.php is included

Answer (score 0):

Is there spacing above the html text?

You can also try to `echo` the text (this would solve your spacing problem).

But dont foget to escape unwanted characters

Comment: I dont want to echo bunch of html code because html tags then are not trackable through editors. it is a good practice to shorten the use of echo and not to put all html stuff in a big echo.

Comment: I don't do it. Im just suggesting to try it out and see what happens. Even though you added more detail, it isn't exactly helpful... (so guessing is all people can do)

Comment: ok. I did so and nothing has been changed. the "" already exists there

Answer (score 0):

If you've commented out the includes and the single quote is not displayed then the quick way to track it down is to temporarily echo a short string such as `echo 'z';`. Keep repositioning it and reloading the browser, eventually you'll notice the 'z' character being output *after* the single quote and you'll have zoned in at where the output is being generated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved using "UTF-8 without BOM" encoding instead of "UTF-8" for header.php (or whatever included file).
I did not get the idea why those 5 people marked my question as spam!!! or whatever.